# Toggling SIM2 on and off

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, app-widgets, dual-sim

Is there any widgets available for toggling the SIM2 turn on and off. I have Samsung J7 dual sim phone and for internet/data, I use SIM2. For getting maximum battery life, I would like to turn off the SIM2 and turn it on whenever I need internet.

Please let me know if you know any android feature or widget or shortcut other than Settings->SIM Card Manager -> SIM2 - Turn On/Off.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Nope. I got a work around like, I installed Nova launcher which has a widget for Activity. I choose it for SIM Card manager and selected the SIM 2 on/off screen. After I turn on or off the SIM2, I will click the home button to go back instead of back button. This will help me to come back to SIM 2 on/off screen always on that widget click :)